# How to implement 3d maneuver gear physics in unity?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rotation

I am trying to create a attack on titan styled game for a school project. I am not new to programming, but I am new to game development. I couldn't find any resources for this, hence I am posting it here.

How do I go about implementing 3d maneuver gear physics from attack on titan anime?

**What is it?**

In case you don't know, here's a brief link about 3d maneuver gear.

[A brief commentary about 3dMG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lkebLo1EmM)

It's basically a grappling hook based system (similar to what you would find in a spiderman game), but it has different components to it, which makes it quite complex to think about.

**My Approach so far**

I have seen tutorials on how to use hooks in unity and stuff, but it would be great if someone could give me a general idea as to how to even start with this kind of thing. I would appreciate your answer, even though it is not unity specific.

The idea is to have two points on the character, from where we fire the ropes. These ropes could simply be graphics (or unity's RaycastHit). And then we would also need information about the hook "hit point". Once we know that, we just reel in ourselves towards that. However the problem is that I don't know how to use momentum etc to effect the character's movement. Also since it's not just one rope(like a spiderman's game), but two, it's even difficult to think as to how would the movement be if user uses only left hook, or right hook or both. Also there is this gas aspect, which would propel you further and it should also be taken into account, along with momentum that we would carry.

So any general idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the components you are looking for are [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) for an object which maintains momentum and the [SpringJoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint.html) to model the ropes. Spring joints can stretch and will then exert a force which retracts the connected object. This can be used to propel it forward.

You can add multiple spring-joints to an object which connect it to other objects. When you have one joint connecting the character to building A and one connecting the character to building B, both of their forces will apply and the character will move to where the equilibrium lies.

A directional acceleration which doesn't come from the springs (the "propelling gas") can be implemented by [adding a force](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) to the rigidbody.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do understand that spring joints are needed, but do you have intuition as to how to implement these spring-joints with the propelling gas that I mentioned? Also how do I go about having two spring-joints because there are two ropes that should effect the characters movement. Thanks

Comment: @posixKing Answer updated.